# Working together questions

Tags: word-problem

Two tractors working together cultivated  2 3  of a field in 4 days. How long would it take each tractor to cultivate the whole field by itself if the first tractor can do the job 5 days faster than the second?

This are my weak type of problems. can someone show me a detailed solution so i can memorize the "formula" . thx

Comment: Did you mean $2/3$ of a field?

Comment: These problems are really designed to get you thinking about how to translate a problem into a mathematical statement, which you can then solve. Do you know how to solve simultaneous equations, such as $2x-y=5, y+4x=7$? Could this problem be stated in a similar way? You need to think about each tractor's $rate$ of doing work...

Comment: @AmpleMimic i can solve thos equations but i cant translate it plz help

Comment: I'm just writing an answer to a related question...

Comment: @AmpleMimic okay take ur time

Comment: @AmpleMimic i first got 1/x + 1/y = x+y/xy. Then i found the recipricol and got xy/(x+y). I then from the 2nd sentence made that x = y+5. I substituded that in and now im stuck. plz help.

Comment: i got 10 and 15 thx very much for no help at all.

Comment: Ha ha... OK! Usually math.stack members won't directly answer questions that seem to be homework or similar. Rather, they will try to provide examples or hints. I'm glad you got the correct answers, though.

Comment: im sorry i was just stressed out sorry thx for the help @AmpleMimic

Comment: @AmpleMimic plz read the comment above

Comment: No problem, Dan!

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer a related question.

*It takes Alice 2 hours to dig a hole, and Bob 3 hours to dig a hole. How long if they work together?*

OK. The trick is to *identify the variable* that will allow you to solve this. Here it is the speed of hole-digging, or, better, *rate* of hole digging. It's quite hard to spot when you first try these problems, but they are often based around *rates*.

The rate at which Alice digs a hole is $1/2$ holes per hour. The rate at which Bob digs is $1/3$ holes per hour. Their combined rate is $1/2+1/3=5/6$ holes per hour. In one hour, they dig $5/6$ of a hole.

How many hours are needed per hole? This is just the reciprocal ("1 over...") of the rate, $1/(5/6)=6/5$ hours, or 1 hour 12 minutes.

In your tractor question, we can call the first tractor's rate of doing work $x$, and the second $y$. The units could be fields plowed per day. How long would it take both tractors to completely plow a field? What equation could we set up given the information in the second sentence?